# Issue updating to Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a problem with updating from Angular 2 to Angular 4. I face this problem when I install new npm packages.

[image]

What does it mean and how I can solve it? I have installed @angular/platform-browser@4.0.3.

Comment: probably some of your third-party lib has dependencies on these versions.  if all of them complain about 4.0.x and you are have 4.0.0 in you package json for angular i would ignore it for now and proceed with upgrade